# How to read each line in a file separated by delimiters and spaces

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have written a small shell script to get some values from a text file and have them in a for loop to use them as a variables which I will be using as an input to a wsadmin command. Below is the shell script I have written.

```
FILE=`cat test.txt`

for i in `echo "$FILE"`

do
DS_NAME=`echo "$i"|awk -F"=" '{print $2}'`
HOST_NAME=`echo "$i"|awk -F"=" '{print $2}'`
PORT_NUMBER=`echo "$i"|awk -F"=" '{print $3}'`
DB_NAME=`echo "$i"|awk -F"=" '{print $4}'`

echo "$DS_NAME"

echo "$HOST_NAME"

echo "$PORT_NUMBER"

echo "$DB_NAME"

done
```

The contents of my test.txt file are below.

```
test connection data source=test.connect.com=1234=testdb
test connection data source=test1.connect.com=1134=test1db
test connection data source=test2.connect.com=1234=test2db
```

When I execute the shell script I'm looking for an output like below.

```
test connection data source
test1.connect.com
1234
testdb
```

But unfortunately I'm not getting what I needed and I believe its because of the spaces between words in DS_NAME.How can I get around this ? Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

`` FILE=`cat test.txt` `` stores the content of the file (except for trailing newlines) in the variable `FILE`. Then `echo "$FILE"` prints the file content (assuming that it doesn't start with a dash and doesn't contain any backslashes). It would have been simpler to directly write

```
for i in `cat test.txt`
```

Next, the command substitution `` `…` `` in a context that allows word splitting breaks the output of the command into words, not lines. (This is a default and it can be changed, although that's not the best way to solve your problem.) That's your visible problem: the loop runs once for each word, not once for each line. In addition, the words are treated as shell wildcard pattern: if there's a line like `test * source=a=b=c`, the `*` will be replaced by the list of file names in the current directory.

Using awk to extract fields from the line works (apart from the mangling from `echo`), but it's overly complicated and slow.

There's a shell builtin that reads a line and splits it into fields: [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read). Just use that. To use the character `=` as the field delimiter, set the variable `IFS` for the `read` command. Pass the option `-r` to `read` unless you want to treat a backslash at the end of a line as indicating a continuation line.

```
while IFS='=' read -r DS_NAME HOST_NAME PORT_NUMBER DB_NAME ignored; do
  …
done <test.txt
```

The extra variable `ignored` makes your parser more robust in case there's an extra field, e.g.

```
test connection data source=test.connect.com=1234=testdb=hey, a new field
```

Comment: Gilles - Thank you very much. This worked like a charm.Really appreciate it.